# Integrity constraint violation: 1451 not raised with sqlite

Tags: mysql, sqlite, symfony, doctrine

I have written a code that should failed because of foreign key. On an entity I have add a field with a foreign constraint.

```
<?php

namespace CoreBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="experience")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="CoreBundle\Repository\ExperienceRepository") 
 */
Experience{
  /**
   * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Relationship", mappedBy="experience")
   */
  private $relationships;

  public function __construct()
  {
      $this->relationships = new ArrayCollection();
  }

}
```

When I tried to `DELETE` an experience mysql raise a classic

```
An exception occurred while executing 'DELETE FROM experience WHERE id = ?' 
with params [127]:\n\nSQLSTATE[23000]:
Integrity constraint violation: 1451 
Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

I have no problem with this error. I know why I have it and what to do to fix it.

But when I swap to sqlite, no errors is raised. I use sqlite to run my test outside of DB, I assumed mysql and sqlite behave the same way.

What is happening with sqlite?

Edit : It seems that foreign keys are not activated be default on sqlite. The documentation explain how to activate it by CLI, but how to configure this in symfony ?

Comment: The error is pretty obvious. A record you want to delete has a relation to a record in another table which needs to be deleted first.

Comment: Is the constraint set correctly in the SQLite database? Also note that [foreign keys need to be enabled correctly to function](https://sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_enable).

Comment: I let doctrine configure the constraint. It is well set in MySQL so assume it is the for sqlite. I was not aware of this configuration.
Here again I let symfony handle it. But I will investigate.

Comment: @Jerome Note [this bug](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/issues/2104) that was closed as Invalid. Due to various issues, Doctrine does not appear to consider SQLite a foreign key supporting database.

Comment: @Jerome Read this. [Bidirectional one-to-many cascade remove and orphanRemoval operations in doctrine](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/ur2x/bidirectional-one-to-many-cascade-remove-and-orphan-removal-operations-in-doctrine)

Comment: @BentCoder thanks for your link. even if this is not the question. I am sorry if I have not been clear.

Comment: @Phylogenesis I have seen it in the github bugtracker but I am not sure of what this mean. So there is no way of enabling Foreign key with sqlite and doctrine?

Comment: @Jerome That looks to be the case. Doctrine's abstraction layer for SQLite is set such that it specifies it [doesn't support foreign keys](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Platforms/SqlitePlatform.php#L727). As such, any attempts to use them are silently ignored.